# Join Recursion Problematic on Left Join in Propel ORM

Tags: php, orm, propel

With Propel ORM (1.6.5), when I joinWith() a table "A" to table "B" and then later call toArray() on the result PropelObjectCollection, the entry for B in each A record contains all the records for A again (see dump below).

A is LEFT JOINd to B. Each record in A points to exactly one in B. Code I am using:

```
$oAQuery = AQuery::create()
  ->joinB('b', Criteria::LEFT_JOIN)
    ->useBQuery()
        ->_if(strlen($sB))
          ->filterByBField1(str_replace(' ', '%', $sCity))
        ->_endif()
      ->endUse()
  ->with('b');

$oCollection = $oAQuery->find();
$aArray = $oAQuery->toArray();
```

toArray() dump:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Field1] => 29
            [Field2] => 0
            [B] => Array
                (
                    [BField1] => 7
                    [BField2] => 10
                    [As] => Array
                        (
                            [A_0] => *RECURSION*
                            [A_1] => Array
                                (
                                    [Field1] = 234
                                    [Field2] = 3424
                                    ...
```

I want to stop this, primarily, because there are many records and with the recursion I easily go over a 512m memory_limit for PHP (i even did 2048m for a test, still went over)

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own formatter, so that you can decide what to do with the result set: http://www.propelorm.org/reference/model-criteria.html#using_an_alternative_formatter.

Using a custom formatter requires an extra method call:

```
$aArray = $oAQuery->setFormatter('MyCustomFormatter')->find();
// instead of $aArray = $oAQuery->toArray();
```